# Prompt before submitting question

Tags: feature-request, editor

This has happened a couple of times to me now, and I'm not sure how I'm doing it. I'll be in the middle of writing a question and somehow submit my question before it's complete. It would be nice if there was a prompt "are you sure you want to submit your question" or something.

Has anyone else had this issue?

More info:
It appears that hitting tab a couple of times (ie if you were trying to align code and forgot you were in a web form) and then hitting enter will submit the question if the submit button is highlighted.

Comment: Submitting a question doesn't happen on "enter", so I'm not entirely sure if this would be useful.  It does take a conscious action to submit a question.

Comment: @Makoto that's what I thought, but in both of these instances I didn't intestinally click save

Comment: So you're telling me it's possible to submit a question just by you hitting the Enter key?  That's what I'm getting at here.

Comment: This has never happened to me, ever. This would probably be a bug, on Stack Overflow's or your end. Can you try and localize what exactly triggers the question getting posted?

Comment: @Pekka웃  so, I think I figured out the issue.  I believe that, in my focus on writing the question, I was hitting tab like I was in VS, and then hitting enter while the submit button was highlighted.  This WILL submit the question when hitting enter.

Comment: Maybe a TAB + ENTER happened?

Comment: Tab + Enter gets me occasionally too. Is there some reason that tabs don't correspond to tab characters when answering questions and such?  The only thing I can think of is maybe for accessibility purposes

Comment: hmm you can always go in and edit your question, immediately. Adding another step to confirm a question when the whole point is to make it easier to ask them seems counter productive.

Comment: @pal4life yeah, it's just obnoxious when people immediately downvote you and vtc cause you accidentally submitted the question before it was complete...

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Standard thing for a tab to do is to change elements so that is what the site does.

Comment: @DForck42 I totally agree with you on that comment. It seems the downvote folks need to chill out a bit and may be there should be a grace period until a question can be voted down like an hour or so or atleast some feedback provided before that. Funny actually one of my most popular question with 75,000 vote is actually closed. Go figure.

Comment: @DForck42 In case you notice you accidentially posted your question, immediately delete it, edit to finish and undelete again.

Comment: I just tried this on one of my old questions and wasn't able to edit it while it was deleted.  @zero298 you'd have to ask a mod to delete it and then ask them to undelete.  Or wait until the community votes you down to the point where your question can be deleted by other users, which doesn't exactly help the situation :/  I guess the only real solution right now is a quick edit to say SORRY STILL EDITING or something at the top.  Would be nice to have a real solution for this.

Comment: @Will maybe just a message if it's being edited by the OP within a certain time range that says "still being edited by asker" or something like that, so that those looking at it can know that its still being worked on

Comment: @Will No need to do any of that.  Just delete the question, make your changes in a regular word processor/text editor, then undelete and immediate apply your changes.  No need to get anyone else involved or keep the question on the site in an unfit state.

Comment: I just edit my question in a text editor and when I'm sure I'm ready, copy and paste it into the question box... but maybe I'm weird.

Comment: Reasonable solutions.